# Django: users inexplicably being logged out

Tags: django, authentication

Users of my Django app recently started to report that they are being logged off in the middle of interacting with the app. It obviously isn't due to the session expiring (which iirc is by default 2 weeks after sign in).

What could be the reasons for Django logging them out? e.g. could this be related to frequent server restarts that I'm doing while updating the app's code?

Comment: What is your session storage backend? Do you by any chance have hardcoded urls in your links? For example users using your site with www.example.com but clicking on a link example.com?

Comment: I had a similar issue when I changed my web server keep-alive setting

Comment: Are your users accessing different Django sites which have the same `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` value?  It's best to have a unique `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` value for each django site.